# How to find maximum number of different strings?

Tags: text-processing, scripting, sort

I have a file:

```
2.0-00-04
2.0-00-03
2.0-00-02
2.0-00-01
2.0-00-00
1.0-00-02
1.0-00-01
1.0-00-00
```

How can I find maximum number of each group? In the string above, output should be:

```
2.0-00-04
1.0-00-02
```

Comment: What is exactly a group? (`1.0` and `2.0` or `1` and `2` or `1.0-00-0` and `2.0-00-0` ...)

Comment: group is 2.0, 1.0

Answer (score 2):

Below there is one solution:

```
sort -rn file | uniq -w3
```

Comment: OP's input is already sorted, so `uniq -w3 file.txt` will do..